# Find shortest path to one of many nodes with attribute

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, networkx

I have a networkx graph representing the minimum spanning tree of roughly 1 million objects (vertices). I am wondering if there is an efficient way to find the shortest path between a given vertex and one of many other vertices.

Here is an example graph with a smaller number of vertices (110)

```
nodes = [(0.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (1.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (2.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (3.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (4.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (5.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (6.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (7.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (8.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (9.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (10.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (11.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (12.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (13.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (14.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (15.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (16.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (17.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (18.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (19.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (20.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (21.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (22.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (23.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (24.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (25.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (26.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (27.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (28.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (29.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (30.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (31.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (32.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (33.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (34.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (35.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (36.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (37.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (38.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (39.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (40.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (41.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (42.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (43.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (44.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (45.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (46.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (47.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (48.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (49.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (50.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (51.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (52.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (53.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (54.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (55.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (56.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (57.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (58.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (59.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (60.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (61.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (62.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (63.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (64.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (65.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (66.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (67.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (68.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (69.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (70.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (71.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (72.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (73.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (74.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (75.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (76.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (77.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (78.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (79.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (80.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (81.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (82.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (83.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (84.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (85.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (86.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (87.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (88.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (89.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (90.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (91.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (92.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (93.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (94.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (95.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (96.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (97.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (98.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (99.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (100.0, {'label': -1}) ,
         (101.0, {'label': -1}) ,
         (102.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (103.0, {'label': -1}) ,
         (104.0, {'label': -1}) ,
         (105.0, {'label': -1}) ,
         (106.0, {'label': -1}) ,
         (107.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (108.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (109.0, {'label': -1})]
edges = [(0.0, 25.0, {'weight': 1.3788141613435239}) ,
         (0.0, 15.0, {'weight': 1.1948288781935414}) ,
         (1.0, 99.0, {'weight': 2.1024875417678257}) ,
         (1.0, 52.0, {'weight': 1.5298566582843918}) ,
         (2.0, 59.0, {'weight': 1.2222170767316791}) ,
         (3.0, 96.0, {'weight': 0.77235026806254947}) ,
         (3.0, 98.0, {'weight': 0.75540026318653475}) ,
         (3.0, 83.0, {'weight': 0.63745598060956865}) ,
         (4.0, 8.0, {'weight': 1.1460983565815646}) ,
         (5.0, 39.0, {'weight': 0.57882005244148982}) ,
         (6.0, 27.0, {'weight': 0.77903808587705414}) ,
         (6.0, 38.0, {'weight': 0.87763345274858739}) ,
         (7.0, 83.0, {'weight': 1.0592473391743824}) ,
         (7.0, 52.0, {'weight': 1.1650063193499598}) ,
         (8.0, 18.0, {'weight': 0.62985157194068553}) ,
         (8.0, 63.0, {'weight': 0.66061808561292024}) ,
         (9.0, 57.0, {'weight': 0.73138423240527128}) ,
         (9.0, 14.0, {'weight': 0.68690071596776681}) ,
         (10.0, 43.0, {'weight': 1.0938913337235003}) ,
         (11.0, 76.0, {'weight': 1.8066534138474315}) ,
         (11.0, 22.0, {'weight': 1.5814274601380762}) ,
         (12.0, 68.0, {'weight': 0.82964162447510292}) ,
         (12.0, 28.0, {'weight': 0.56687613489965616}) ,
         (13.0, 41.0, {'weight': 0.67883257822079479}) ,
         (13.0, 70.0, {'weight': 0.69594526555853065}) ,
         (13.0, 39.0, {'weight': 0.62690609201673064}) ,
         (14.0, 42.0, {'weight': 0.51384098628821639}) ,
         (15.0, 91.0, {'weight': 0.80363040334950342}) ,
         (15.0, 63.0, {'weight': 0.74055429404201112}) ,
         (16.0, 75.0, {'weight': 0.89225782872169068}) ,
         (16.0, 36.0, {'weight': 0.97796463842832249}) ,
         (16.0, 61.0, {'weight': 1.2426060084547763}) ,
         (17.0, 24.0, {'weight': 0.48569989925661516}) ,
         (17.0, 88.0, {'weight': 0.58411688395739225}) ,
         (17.0, 42.0, {'weight': 0.48569989925661516}) ,
         (18.0, 19.0, {'weight': 0.73750301595928458}) ,
         (18.0, 87.0, {'weight': 0.62985157194068553}) ,
         (19.0, 80.0, {'weight': 0.77740196142918039}) ,
         (20.0, 53.0, {'weight': 1.5817584651620507}) ,
         (21.0, 33.0, {'weight': 1.558483049272277}) ,
         (21.0, 35.0, {'weight': 1.022218339608882}) ,
         (22.0, 93.0, {'weight': 1.4628634684132413}) ,
         (22.0, 101.0, {'weight': 7.494583622053641}) ,
         (23.0, 97.0, {'weight': 0.86085201141197409}) ,
         (23.0, 90.0, {'weight': 1.4629842172999594}) ,
         (23.0, 65.0, {'weight': 0.94746570241498318}) ,
         (24.0, 34.0, {'weight': 0.55323853417352553}) ,
         (25.0, 104.0, {'weight': 4.9839694794161371}) ,
         (26.0, 85.0, {'weight': 1.5024751933287497}) ,
         (26.0, 46.0, {'weight': 1.2053565344116006}) ,
         (27.0, 72.0, {'weight': 0.72860577250944303}) ,
         (27.0, 92.0, {'weight': 0.74002007166874428}) ,
         (28.0, 54.0, {'weight': 0.55323853417352553}) ,
         (29.0, 50.0, {'weight': 0.81426784351619774}) ,
         (30.0, 98.0, {'weight': 0.77235026806254947}) ,
         (30.0, 78.0, {'weight': 0.79413937142096647}) ,
         (30.0, 95.0, {'weight': 0.78901093530213129}) ,
         (31.0, 68.0, {'weight': 0.98851671776185412}) ,
         (32.0, 95.0, {'weight': 0.8579399666494596}) ,
         (34.0, 54.0, {'weight': 0.55323853417352553}) ,
         (34.0, 55.0, {'weight': 0.60906522381767525}) ,
         (35.0, 62.0, {'weight': 0.66697239833732958}) ,
         (36.0, 93.0, {'weight': 1.2932994772208264}) ,
         (37.0, 80.0, {'weight': 0.85527462610640648}) ,
         (37.0, 96.0, {'weight': 0.85527462610640648}) ,
         (38.0, 46.0, {'weight': 0.95334944284759993}) ,
         (39.0, 50.0, {'weight': 0.52028039541706872}) ,
         (40.0, 69.0, {'weight': 1.7931323073700682}) ,
         (42.0, 62.0, {'weight': 0.51384098628821639}) ,
         (42.0, 81.0, {'weight': 0.5466147583189902}) ,
         (43.0, 65.0, {'weight': 1.0581157274507453}) ,
         (44.0, 108.0, {'weight': 3.0598509599260266}) ,
         (44.0, 70.0, {'weight': 1.0805691635112824}) ,
         (45.0, 56.0, {'weight': 1.3420236519319457}) ,
         (45.0, 79.0, {'weight': 1.6201017824952586}) ,
         (46.0, 53.0, {'weight': 1.070516213146298}) ,
         (47.0, 78.0, {'weight': 1.2822937333699174}) ,
         (47.0, 103.0, {'weight': 3.9053251231648707}) ,
         (48.0, 97.0, {'weight': 0.86085201141197409}) ,
         (48.0, 67.0, {'weight': 0.75656062694199944}) ,
         (49.0, 94.0, {'weight': 1.6216528905308547}) ,
         (49.0, 86.0, {'weight': 0.80157999082131093}) ,
         (49.0, 62.0, {'weight': 0.7081136236724922}) ,
         (51.0, 102.0, {'weight': 1.4704389417937378}) ,
         (51.0, 71.0, {'weight': 0.83506431983724716}) ,
         (54.0, 75.0, {'weight': 0.70074754481170742}) ,
         (55.0, 58.0, {'weight': 0.78571631647476448}) ,
         (56.0, 82.0, {'weight': 1.3387438494166808}) ,
         (57.0, 84.0, {'weight': 1.558483049272277}) ,
         (59.0, 64.0, {'weight': 1.0416266944398496}) ,
         (60.0, 98.0, {'weight': 1.2534403896544031}) ,
         (63.0, 73.0, {'weight': 0.83646303763566465}) ,
         (64.0, 72.0, {'weight': 0.8620326535711742}) ,
         (66.0, 77.0, {'weight': 0.79981721989351606}) ,
         (67.0, 72.0, {'weight': 0.74002007166874428}) ,
         (69.0, 83.0, {'weight': 1.5000235782351021}) ,
         (70.0, 77.0, {'weight': 0.75999034076724692}) ,
         (71.0, 88.0, {'weight': 0.66450874893016454}) ,
         (74.0, 97.0, {'weight': 0.8743417572549379}) ,
         (76.0, 107.0, {'weight': 2.0300278349030831}) ,
         (77.0, 89.0, {'weight': 0.75999034076724692}) ,
         (79.0, 106.0, {'weight': 4.5661761296968333}) ,
         (82.0, 95.0, {'weight': 1.083633962514291}) ,
         (84.0, 99.0, {'weight': 2.1024875417678257}) ,
         (89.0, 92.0, {'weight': 0.75419548272456249}) ,
         (100.0, 107.0, {'weight': 2.9259491743365307}) ,
         (101.0, 109.0, {'weight': 7.6747981730730297}) ,
         (102.0, 108.0, {'weight': 4.3128725576385092}) ,
         (104.0, 105.0, {'weight': 7.5515191839631273})]
G2 = nx.Graph()
G2.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G2.add_edges_from(edges)
```

What I want is "which vertex that has label >= 0 is closest to each of the vertices with label = -1". With a small graph like this, the brute force approach using something like `nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length()` and then checking the labels works fine, but it doesn't scale to very large graphs. Are there more efficient algorithms, especially if built-in to networkx, that I could use?

UPDATE:

I used the excellent suggestion by Richard and the comment below to write this. What I actually want is an array of labels, which I think made things less messy than Richard alluded to in networkx. The whole relabeling took 45 seconds on a dataset that took an hour to do by brute force!

```
def relabel(G, indices_to_relabel):
    """ 
    Update the anomaly labels to be the closest cluster.
    """
    # Add a "special" node that has zero weight to all the cluster nodes
    print('Adding special node')
    G.add_node('special', {'label': 'special'})
    special_edges = [(n, 'special', {'weight': 0}) 
                     for n, ndat in G.nodes_iter(data=True) 
                     if ndat['label'] != 'special' and ndat['label'] >= 0]
    G.add_edges_from(special_edges)

    print('Calculating path from special node to all other nodes')
    paths = nx.shortest_path(G, source='special', target=None, weight='weight')

    print('Updating labels')
    new_labels = np.array([ndat['label'] for _, ndat in G.nodes_iter(data=True)])
    new_labels[indices_to_relabel] = [G.node[paths[n][1]]['label'] for n in indices_to_relabel]

    # Clean up
    G.remove_node('special')
    return new_labels
```

Comment: Here is there any edge length ? Or are they uniform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's such an algorithm built into networkx, but it does seem as though it would be sensible to have an algorithm which expands the least-cost path until a condition is reached. However, even though networkx does not include such a capability, it's pretty easy to build an algorithm to do this.

- Call the nodes with `label==-1` the source nodes.
- Call the node with `label>=0` which is closest to a source node its target node. Our goal is to find the target nodes.
- Create a new node. This will be the *special* node.
- Connect all of the potential target nodes to the special node with edges of weight 0.
- For each source node, find the shortest path to the special node. The penultimate node on this path is necessarily a target node and is the closest one to the source node.
- When finished, eliminate the special node and all its connecting edges.

If the number of source nodes is *S*, this algorithm runs in *O(S(|E|+|V| log |V|))* time (assuming the shortest path algorithm is Dijkstra).

(It may be that I've misunderstood whether you want the -1's closest to the >=0's or the >=0's closest to the -1's. If I have, just invert the source/target labeling.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import networkx as nx

nodes = [(0.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (1.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (2.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (3.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (4.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (5.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (6.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (7.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (8.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (9.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (10.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (11.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (12.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (13.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (14.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (15.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (16.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (17.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (18.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (19.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (20.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (21.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (22.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (23.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (24.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (25.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (26.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (27.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (28.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (29.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (30.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (31.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (32.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (33.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (34.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (35.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (36.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (37.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (38.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (39.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (40.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (41.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (42.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (43.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (44.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (45.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (46.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (47.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (48.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (49.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (50.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (51.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (52.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (53.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (54.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (55.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (56.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (57.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (58.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (59.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (60.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (61.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (62.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (63.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (64.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (65.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (66.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (67.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (68.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (69.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (70.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (71.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (72.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (73.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (74.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (75.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (76.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (77.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (78.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (79.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (80.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (81.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (82.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (83.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (84.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (85.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (86.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (87.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (88.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (89.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (90.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (91.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (92.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (93.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (94.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (95.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (96.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (97.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (98.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (99.0, {'label': 2}) ,
         (100.0, {'label': -1}) ,
         (101.0, {'label': -1}) ,
         (102.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (103.0, {'label': -1}) ,
         (104.0, {'label': -1}) ,
         (105.0, {'label': -1}) ,
         (106.0, {'label': -1}) ,
         (107.0, {'label': 1}) ,
         (108.0, {'label': 0}) ,
         (109.0, {'label': -1})]
edges = [(0.0, 25.0, {'weight': 1.3788141613435239}) ,
         (0.0, 15.0, {'weight': 1.1948288781935414}) ,
         (1.0, 99.0, {'weight': 2.1024875417678257}) ,
         (1.0, 52.0, {'weight': 1.5298566582843918}) ,
         (2.0, 59.0, {'weight': 1.2222170767316791}) ,
         (3.0, 96.0, {'weight': 0.77235026806254947}) ,
         (3.0, 98.0, {'weight': 0.75540026318653475}) ,
         (3.0, 83.0, {'weight': 0.63745598060956865}) ,
         (4.0, 8.0, {'weight': 1.1460983565815646}) ,
         (5.0, 39.0, {'weight': 0.57882005244148982}) ,
         (6.0, 27.0, {'weight': 0.77903808587705414}) ,
         (6.0, 38.0, {'weight': 0.87763345274858739}) ,
         (7.0, 83.0, {'weight': 1.0592473391743824}) ,
         (7.0, 52.0, {'weight': 1.1650063193499598}) ,
         (8.0, 18.0, {'weight': 0.62985157194068553}) ,
         (8.0, 63.0, {'weight': 0.66061808561292024}) ,
         (9.0, 57.0, {'weight': 0.73138423240527128}) ,
         (9.0, 14.0, {'weight': 0.68690071596776681}) ,
         (10.0, 43.0, {'weight': 1.0938913337235003}) ,
         (11.0, 76.0, {'weight': 1.8066534138474315}) ,
         (11.0, 22.0, {'weight': 1.5814274601380762}) ,
         (12.0, 68.0, {'weight': 0.82964162447510292}) ,
         (12.0, 28.0, {'weight': 0.56687613489965616}) ,
         (13.0, 41.0, {'weight': 0.67883257822079479}) ,
         (13.0, 70.0, {'weight': 0.69594526555853065}) ,
         (13.0, 39.0, {'weight': 0.62690609201673064}) ,
         (14.0, 42.0, {'weight': 0.51384098628821639}) ,
         (15.0, 91.0, {'weight': 0.80363040334950342}) ,
         (15.0, 63.0, {'weight': 0.74055429404201112}) ,
         (16.0, 75.0, {'weight': 0.89225782872169068}) ,
         (16.0, 36.0, {'weight': 0.97796463842832249}) ,
         (16.0, 61.0, {'weight': 1.2426060084547763}) ,
         (17.0, 24.0, {'weight': 0.48569989925661516}) ,
         (17.0, 88.0, {'weight': 0.58411688395739225}) ,
         (17.0, 42.0, {'weight': 0.48569989925661516}) ,
         (18.0, 19.0, {'weight': 0.73750301595928458}) ,
         (18.0, 87.0, {'weight': 0.62985157194068553}) ,
         (19.0, 80.0, {'weight': 0.77740196142918039}) ,
         (20.0, 53.0, {'weight': 1.5817584651620507}) ,
         (21.0, 33.0, {'weight': 1.558483049272277}) ,
         (21.0, 35.0, {'weight': 1.022218339608882}) ,
         (22.0, 93.0, {'weight': 1.4628634684132413}) ,
         (22.0, 101.0, {'weight': 7.494583622053641}) ,
         (23.0, 97.0, {'weight': 0.86085201141197409}) ,
         (23.0, 90.0, {'weight': 1.4629842172999594}) ,
         (23.0, 65.0, {'weight': 0.94746570241498318}) ,
         (24.0, 34.0, {'weight': 0.55323853417352553}) ,
         (25.0, 104.0, {'weight': 4.9839694794161371}) ,
         (26.0, 85.0, {'weight': 1.5024751933287497}) ,
         (26.0, 46.0, {'weight': 1.2053565344116006}) ,
         (27.0, 72.0, {'weight': 0.72860577250944303}) ,
         (27.0, 92.0, {'weight': 0.74002007166874428}) ,
         (28.0, 54.0, {'weight': 0.55323853417352553}) ,
         (29.0, 50.0, {'weight': 0.81426784351619774}) ,
         (30.0, 98.0, {'weight': 0.77235026806254947}) ,
         (30.0, 78.0, {'weight': 0.79413937142096647}) ,
         (30.0, 95.0, {'weight': 0.78901093530213129}) ,
         (31.0, 68.0, {'weight': 0.98851671776185412}) ,
         (32.0, 95.0, {'weight': 0.8579399666494596}) ,
         (34.0, 54.0, {'weight': 0.55323853417352553}) ,
         (34.0, 55.0, {'weight': 0.60906522381767525}) ,
         (35.0, 62.0, {'weight': 0.66697239833732958}) ,
         (36.0, 93.0, {'weight': 1.2932994772208264}) ,
         (37.0, 80.0, {'weight': 0.85527462610640648}) ,
         (37.0, 96.0, {'weight': 0.85527462610640648}) ,
         (38.0, 46.0, {'weight': 0.95334944284759993}) ,
         (39.0, 50.0, {'weight': 0.52028039541706872}) ,
         (40.0, 69.0, {'weight': 1.7931323073700682}) ,
         (42.0, 62.0, {'weight': 0.51384098628821639}) ,
         (42.0, 81.0, {'weight': 0.5466147583189902}) ,
         (43.0, 65.0, {'weight': 1.0581157274507453}) ,
         (44.0, 108.0, {'weight': 3.0598509599260266}) ,
         (44.0, 70.0, {'weight': 1.0805691635112824}) ,
         (45.0, 56.0, {'weight': 1.3420236519319457}) ,
         (45.0, 79.0, {'weight': 1.6201017824952586}) ,
         (46.0, 53.0, {'weight': 1.070516213146298}) ,
         (47.0, 78.0, {'weight': 1.2822937333699174}) ,
         (47.0, 103.0, {'weight': 3.9053251231648707}) ,
         (48.0, 97.0, {'weight': 0.86085201141197409}) ,
         (48.0, 67.0, {'weight': 0.75656062694199944}) ,
         (49.0, 94.0, {'weight': 1.6216528905308547}) ,
         (49.0, 86.0, {'weight': 0.80157999082131093}) ,
         (49.0, 62.0, {'weight': 0.7081136236724922}) ,
         (51.0, 102.0, {'weight': 1.4704389417937378}) ,
         (51.0, 71.0, {'weight': 0.83506431983724716}) ,
         (54.0, 75.0, {'weight': 0.70074754481170742}) ,
         (55.0, 58.0, {'weight': 0.78571631647476448}) ,
         (56.0, 82.0, {'weight': 1.3387438494166808}) ,
         (57.0, 84.0, {'weight': 1.558483049272277}) ,
         (59.0, 64.0, {'weight': 1.0416266944398496}) ,
         (60.0, 98.0, {'weight': 1.2534403896544031}) ,
         (63.0, 73.0, {'weight': 0.83646303763566465}) ,
         (64.0, 72.0, {'weight': 0.8620326535711742}) ,
         (66.0, 77.0, {'weight': 0.79981721989351606}) ,
         (67.0, 72.0, {'weight': 0.74002007166874428}) ,
         (69.0, 83.0, {'weight': 1.5000235782351021}) ,
         (70.0, 77.0, {'weight': 0.75999034076724692}) ,
         (71.0, 88.0, {'weight': 0.66450874893016454}) ,
         (74.0, 97.0, {'weight': 0.8743417572549379}) ,
         (76.0, 107.0, {'weight': 2.0300278349030831}) ,
         (77.0, 89.0, {'weight': 0.75999034076724692}) ,
         (79.0, 106.0, {'weight': 4.5661761296968333}) ,
         (82.0, 95.0, {'weight': 1.083633962514291}) ,
         (84.0, 99.0, {'weight': 2.1024875417678257}) ,
         (89.0, 92.0, {'weight': 0.75419548272456249}) ,
         (100.0, 107.0, {'weight': 2.9259491743365307}) ,
         (101.0, 109.0, {'weight': 7.6747981730730297}) ,
         (102.0, 108.0, {'weight': 4.3128725576385092}) ,
         (104.0, 105.0, {'weight': 7.5515191839631273})]
G2 = nx.Graph()
G2.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G2.add_edges_from(edges)

G2.add_node('special', {'label': 'special'})

special_edges = []
for n, ndat in G2.nodes_iter(data=True):
   if ndat['label']!='special' and ndat['label']>=0:
      special_edges.append( (n,'special', {'weight':0}) )

G2.add_edges_from(special_edges)

for n, ndat in G2.nodes_iter(data=True):
   if ndat['label']==-1:
      path = nx.shortest_path(G2, source=n, target='special', weight='weight')
      ndat['closest'] = path[-2] #Closest node with label>=0

G2.remove_node('special')
```

Comment: Couldn't you do this in one Dijkstra call by searching from the special node to the source nodes?

Comment: Yes, though that is only true for undirected graphs. I did consider your idea when I was writing this, and I think it is the most straight-forward route if you are building your own algorithm; however, implementing it using the networkx framework would be more complex than what I have here.

Comment: you could speed this algorithm up by, after each time you run the shortest path algorithm, go through the nodes in the shortest path keep track of distance from the special node, and delete the shortest path node from the graph. Each time you delete a node, connect its neighbours to the special node with the appropriate calculated distance. (and each deleted node, if it's a -1 node, record its solution too).

Comment: @robertking: That _might_ work, but simplicity is a virtue. If you look at OP's edit to their question, their run-time decreased from 1hr to 45s. The potential savings of doing further algorithmic development are probably greatly offset by the development time at this point. Worth experimenting with, perhaps, if the code was being frequently used.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem then you have a travelling salesman problem, which means there is no exact solution faster than (in the worst case) testing ever single possibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = heapq
solution = {}
g = build_nx_graph()
for node in g:
    if label_is_neg_1(node):
        solution[node] = false
        heappush(h, (0, node))
while h:
    distance, node = heappop(h)
    for neighbour, neighbour_dist in iterate_neighbours(g):
        bs = best_solution(neighbour, neighbour_dist)
        if not bs == solution.get(neighbour, bs):
            solution[neighbour] = bs
            heappush(h, (bs, neighbour))
    if len(solution) == len(g):
        break
```

this incomplete pseudocode should start at all the -1 nodes, and "fan out", calculating the distance to all the non -1 nodes in order.